# Adding new rule for emails containing header

Tags: email, automation

Is it possible to create a new rule for mail to perform an action if the message contains a custom header?

I want to automaticaly detect emails that contain the "X-hashcash" header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If you go to `Preferences` `Rules` and `Add Rule` then the first of the condition pop up lists has `Edit header list..` as the last choice. In the dialog click on the `+` and add in `X-hashcash`. Done.

Comment: Just to clarify, unless I'm wrong, there's no way currently to have a rule act on a header simply existing, you have to fill in a value. I was searching for a way to include "any" value or to make my rule react simply to the existence of a specific header but I can't find how. If at least the value of the header allowed range for characters such as regex ranges (a-z0-9). I also tried to reverse the logic and say header "does not contain", but it becomes truthy if the header isn't included in the e-mail at all which is illogical but to be expected, alas.

Comment: To be honest I've stopped supporting Mail on macOS. I assume you've tried 'contains' with '*' It may well be impossible with 'Mail'.